# Group $G= \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/ \langle(4,2)\rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\bullet$ Find an element of order 2 in $G$ and an element of infinite order

$\bullet$ explain why there is only one-nontrivial element of finite order

$\bullet$ To which group is $G$ isomorphic

I looked up similar problems but I'm just getting more confused, If the question would find an element of order 2 in $ \mathbb{Z_n} \oplus \mathbb{Z_n}/ \langle(4,2)\rangle $ for some $n$ it's straight forward but now I'm not sure how an element of order 2  in $G$ looks like I think its $(3,1)$ , but I'm not sure.

Why is there only one element of finite order, doesn't  any element $(k,k)$ with $k$  being a prime $>2$ in $ \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/ \langle(4,2)\rangle $  have infinite order in the Group.

Comment: This goes the same way as the other questions of this type here, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673889/what-is-mathbb-z-oplus-mathbb-z-langle-2-2-rangle-isomorphic-to?rq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171390/find-mathbbz-oplus-mathbbz-langle3-6-rangle-and-determine-if-its?rq=1).

Comment: I think the second question should be "explain why there is only one-nontrivial element of finite order". There are infinitely many elements of infinite order.

Comment: Yes, you are right I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $v_1=(2,1)$ has order $2$ in $G$.
- $v_2=(1,0)$ has infinite order in $G$.
- $n(a,b)$ is $0$ in $G$ iff $(na,nb)=m(4,2)=(4m,2m)$ iff $a=2b$.
- $G \cong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2$ because $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z = v_1 \mathbb Z \oplus v_2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1674326/589

Comment: Thank you for your help.